# Q. less of an impact vs less impact

Tags: grammar, american-english

What is the difference between two things?

I think there is no difference.

Comment: *Impact* in the first phrase is a singular count noun; in the second phrase, it's being used as a mass noun. Beyond that syntactical and subtle semantic distinction, they mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your comment :) very thank you!